# Jnotify delete vs shift delete issue

Tags: java, linux, inotify, jnotify

i am using the java jnotify library. i have some problem monitoring the events for deleted directory.

**In Windows 8:**

**case 1:when i delete a folder with normal delete, it will say folder deleted (with name) not sub-folder and files**

**case 2: when i delete a folder with shift delete, it will say folder deleted (with name) and with sub-folder and files name.**

example: FolderA-->SubFolderA-->a.txt

1. if i delete FolderA with normal delete then it will say "FolderA DELETED"
2. if i delete FolderA with SHIFT delete then it will say "FolderA DELETED" and "SubFolderA DELETED" and "SubFolderA-->a.txt DELETED"

**### LINUX 12.04 ###**

**and 2nd issue with Linux:
1. when i delete a file with normal delete it will not show any notify event.
2. when i delete a file with SHIFT delete it will show DELETE notify event.**

can someone have solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance